Azure VM get Value of Files
Is there a way to get the value in this case xml of a file in a specific path? I want to get this information for every VM i have to know on which version my software is running.
I want to get this information by using the Azure portal

Do you want to get the XML version which in virtual machines, if yes, You can fetch the same information using run command or use azure automation runbooks which allow you to run scripts on multiple VMs at once.

Are you looking for output like this? Here is the XML file on the VM, and here is the resulting output in the Azure portal. here is the result from automation account to fetch multiple VM's

yes this is exactly what i was looking for

Can I post the solution with detailed steps?

that would be nice, currently i am using parts of your script to get it going. But i'm struggling with powershell a bit

Posted solution with PowerShell code. Let me know if still having an issue


Azure VM get Value of Files


Note: Make sure to assign the azure virtual machine administrator role at the subscription level

PowerShell code
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
Set-AzContext -Subscription "Subscription_ID"

# Path of the XML file on each VM
$xmlFilePath = "C:\file.xml"

# Define the PowerShell script that will run on each VM
$script = @"
param (
    [string]`$xmlFilePath
)
[xml]`$xmlContent = Get-Content -Path `"$xmlFilePath`"
`$appName = `$xmlContent.SoftwareInfo.Application.Name
`$appVersion = `$xmlContent.SoftwareInfo.Application.Version
Write-Output "Application Name: `$appName"
Write-Output "Application Version: `$appVersion"
"@

$vms = Get-AzVM

# Loop through each VM and execute the script
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    try {
        # Run the command on the VM
        $result = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -VMName $vm.Name -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptString $script -Parameter @{"xmlFilePath" = $xmlFilePath}

        # Display the VM name along with application information
        Write-Output "VM Name: $($vm.Name)"
        Write-Output "Output from VM:"
        $result.Value | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Output $_.Message
        }
        Write-Output "-----------------------------------"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "Failed to run command on VM $($vm.Name): $_"
    }
}

Here is xml file which in azure VM.

For the single VM , you can use run command from azure portal by navigating to VM > Run command.

For the multiple VM's, you can use automation account with PowerShell script.
Output:

